# Efficient queries across several models using Sails.js waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to find an efficient way to retrieve results which spread across several models. In my example I have three models:

- `Video` which stores video data including the creator of a video
- `User` which stores user data
- `Follower` which stores which users follow which other users

A simplified version of my models looks like this:

```
// Video.js

module.exports = {

attributes: {
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    creator: {
      model: 'User'
    }
  }
};


// User.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    user_name: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
};


 // Follower.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    user: {
      model: 'User'
    },
    follower: {
      model: 'User'
    }
  }
};
```

I realize that I could store the many to many association as a `Collection` in `User` directly, but I also store other values along with it such as when a user started to follow another user and from which destination he did so. In addition, I store lots of similar data and I would like to keep the core Models like `Video` and `User` lean.

So now I am trying to get the 10 latest videos (the creation datetime is stored in the `createdAt` attribute automatically added by waterline) which were created by a user which a given user follows.

Starting with this given user (let's call him `queryingUser`) I am trying to get all the users he follows and use them as input to search for videos. I imagine a call to look like this:

```
Follower.find({where: {follower: queryingUser} , select: ['user']}).exec(function (err, users){

    var userArray = [];

    for (var i=0; i< users.length; i++) userArray.push(users[i].user);

    Video.find({ where: {creator: userArray}, limit: 10, sort: 'createdAt DESC' }).exec(function (err, videos){
        // videos should contain the desired result
    });
});
```

I think according to the [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md) a call like this should work, however, it doesn't seem to retrieve any results.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different approach which would lead to the desired result in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it does actually work. I made a mistake elsewhere in my code, but after I fixed it I got the example to work. Maybe it is still helpful for someone else.